# Create structured JSON object from CSV file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, filereader

I want to create a JSON object from the contents of a CSV file. The CSV file is loaded locally via the `FileReader` API and that seems to work, however I am having trouble structuring the JSON in the desired way.

My code for loading the CSV file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Select local CSV File:</p>
        <input id="csv" type="file">
        <output id="out"> input file content</output>
        <script>
            var fileInput = document.getElementById("csv"),
            readFile = function () {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {

                    // Display CSV file contents
                    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = reader.result;
                };

                reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.files[0]);
            };
            fileInput.addEventListener('change', readFile);
        </script>
    </body>>
</html>
```

The code above allows me to load the contents of the CSV file and display them on the current page. To structure the CSV data into the desired format above I tried the following, however it didn't work to me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            function getFile(inputFile) {
            let file = inputFile.files[0];
            fileReader.readAsText(file);
            }
            function csvJSON(csv){
            var lines=csv.split("\n");
            var result = [];
            var headers=lines[0].split(",");
            for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){
                var obj = {};
                var currentline=lines[i].split(",");
                for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
                    obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
                }
                result.push(obj);
            }
            return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
            }
            function readFile(evt) {
            let parsed = csvJSON(evt.target.result);
            return parsed;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I acquire my expected JSON object(s)? Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Just curious but is this your actual CSV structure? It seems like there should be a newline `\n` character after every 6 entries...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to this would be to iterate through your input CSV data on increments of "6" (where 6 represents the number of different bits of data for each student) to capture all student data per CSV row, and then populate an array of structured JSON objects in the desired format like so:

```js
/* Helper function to perform the CSV to JSON transform */
function convertToJson(inputCsv) {

  /* Split input string by `,` and clean up each item */
  const arrayCsv = inputCsv.split(',').map(s => s.replace(/"/gi, '').trim())

  const outputJson = [];

  /* Iterate through input csv at increments of 6, to capture entire CSV row 
     per iteration */
  for (let i = 6; i < arrayCsv.length; i += 6) {

    /* Extract CSV data for current row, and assign to named variables */
    const [date, firstName, middleName, lastName, uin, rsvpStatus] = 
    arrayCsv.slice(i, i + 6)
    
    /* Populate structured JSON entry for this CSV row */
    outputJson.push({
      uin,
      studentInfo: {
        firstName,
        middleName,
        lastName,
        rsvpStatus
      }
    });
  }

  return outputJson;
}

/* Input CSV data from your exsiting code */
const csv = `"Timestamp", "Enter First Name:", "Enter Middle Initial", 
"Enter Last Name:", "Enter UIN:", "Are you attending the event?",
  "2019/02/22 12:41:56 PM CST", "Jonathan", "Samson", "Rowe", "123456789", 
"No", "2019/02/22 12:44:56 PM CST", "phil", "Aspilla", "beltran", "123456788", 
"Yes"`

const json = convertToJson(csv);

console.log(json);
```

Comment: thanks for your help, it is good work. BTW, whenever local csv file uploaded just like my first part of code then running your function in the same snippet? what is fully working example which allows me to upload local csv file then run your code? sorry for my naive question. Thanks a lot

Comment: @beyond_inifinity glad I could help! sorry not sure I understand - are you wanting me to show you how to integrated the `convertToJson()` function in my answer, with the code in your question?

Comment: yeah, like how can I make the first part of my code and your contributed code together in fully parsing working example? or I don't need my first part of the code? I am sorry for this question. I am going to accept your solution, it is big plus

Comment: @beyond_inifinity glad to hear this has helped, and thanks for accepting the answer. I have created a jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yrsap3ej/ to show how the code can be integrated - hope that helps :)

Comment: @Darce Denny: from your solution, how I can export new produced structured JSON to local drive? any idea?

Comment: Hi there, one method would be to create a temporary download link to the data via a data url , I'll post a link here shortly

Comment: @beyond_inifinity have a look at this https://codepen.io/vidhill/pen/bNPEmX . This lets you download data from your app, to a file on your local machine (ie harddrive). Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

If you are struggling to parse data, you can also use PapaParse, it has a lot of configurations and it's pretty easy to use:

```
// Parse CSV string
var data = Papa.parse(csv);
```

See more information at https://www.papaparse.com/demo

Answer (score 1):

```js
var csv = '"Timestamp","Enter First Name:","Enter Middle Initial","Enter Last Name:","Enter UIN:","Are you attending the event?"\n"2019/02/22 12:41:56 PM CST","Jonathan","Samson","Rowe","123456789","No"\n"2019/02/22 12:44:56 PM CST","phil","Aspilla","beltran","123456788","Yes"';

var csvJSON = function(csv) {
  let vals = csv.split('\n'), ret = [];
  for( let i = 1, len = vals.length; i < len; i++ ){
    let person = vals[i].split(',');
    ret.push({
      uin : person[4],
      studentInfo : {
        firstName : person[1],
        middleName : person[2],
        lastName : person[3],
        rsvpStatus : person[5]
      }
    });
  }
  return JSON.stringify(ret);
}

console.log(csvJSON(csv));
```

This is assuming the structure of the CSV is always the same.